# Perl: Reading file, grabbing specific lines and writing new files

Tags: perl

I have a single input file that has the following format:

```
ATOM      1  CAY GLY X   1      -0.084   0.026  -0.058  1.00  2.67      PEP   
ATOM      2  HY1 GLY X   1      -0.448   1.075  -0.037  1.00  0.00      PEP 
.....
END
ATOM      1  CAY GLY X   1      -0.084   0.026  -0.058  1.00  2.67      PEP   
ATOM      2  HY1 GLY X   1      -0.448   1.075  -0.037  1.00  0.00      PEP
.....
END
```

This pattern repeats 1000 times. I'd like to read the input file and print all the lines between ATOM and END to an output file with a unique name (i.e. output001.pdb). This process needs to occur repeatedly until all the lines of the input file are read.
A sample output file would look like this (output001.pdb):

```
ATOM      1  CAY GLY X   1      -0.084   0.026  -0.058  1.00  2.67      PEP   
ATOM      2  HY1 GLY X   1      -0.448   1.075  -0.037  1.00  0.00      PEP
.....
END
```

This is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'all.pdb';

open my $input_fh, '<', $input or die $!;

my @lines;
my @fh;
while ( <$input_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    if ($lines =~ m/ATOM/ .. m/END/ ) {
    for my $i (1 .. 1000) {
    open $fh[$i], '>', "file-$i" or die $!;
 }       
    print {$fh[$i]} $lines;
    }
 } 
 close ($fh[$i]);
 close ($input_fh);
```

I am not sure if my matching statement is correct given an array. Any suggestions on improvement are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be recursive? Please (re)visit the [help] and read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my assignment, here's what I have so far, please help" are considered off-topic unless you can identify a specific problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Do you want to separate atom records by the `END` from the input file, simply use  [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) .
Then you lookbehind or `\K` for hold the word from spliting.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $handler, "input.pdb";
local $/;
my @file = split(/(?<=END)/, <$handler> );
my $i = 0;


while ($i < $#file)
{
    open my $write,">","output$i.pdb";
    $file[$i]=~s/^\n//g;
    print $write $file[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat straight-forward way to do this which builds on the direction you were headed is as follows;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'all.pdb';
my $file_count = 0;
my $taking_lines = 0;
my $output_fh;

open my $input_fh, '<', $input or die $!;

while ( <$input_fh> ) {
    if (m/ATOM/ and ! $taking_lines) {
      $file_count++;
      my $output_filename = "output" . sprintf("%0.3i", $file_count) . ".pdb";
      open $output_fh, '>', $output_filename or die $!;
      $taking_lines = 1;
    }

    print $output_fh $_ if $taking_lines;

    if (m/END/ and $taking_lines) {
      close $output_fh;
      $taking_lines = 0;
    }
 } 

close $output_fh if $taking_lines ;
print "Created $file_count files.\n" ;
```

This is a little longer than some solutions but is arguably easier to follow and therefore maintain.  If **ATOM** is found and we aren't already taking lines, we simply build the new filename, open the new file and set a flag ($taking_lines).  If we find **END** and we're currently taking lines, we close the file and clear the flag.

In between, we simply print to the output file if the flag is set.  The order these three actions are listed is important.  The check for ATOM has to be *before* the output print or we'll miss the first line (with ATOM).  The check for END must be *after* the output print or we'll close the file to early and miss the END line.

If you check out "perldoc opentut" (meaning "tutorial on open") you'll read how you *can* actually re-use a filehandle - that is, you can pass &open an existing, in-use filehandle and perl will kindly close the "old" file and open the "new" one without fuss.  This opens up ways to shorten the script (like the last 'if' statement could simply be `$taking_lines = 0 if m/END/;` - but, again arguably, its simpler and easier for whoever gets lumped with maintaining your code to not necessarily use such tricks.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain your approach!!